# Reasoning about overlapping inductive definitions in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, proof

I would like to prove the following lemma in Isabelle:

```
lemma "T (Open # xs) ⟹ ¬ S (Open # xs) ⟹ count xs Close ≤ count xs Open"
```

Please find the definitions below:

```
datatype paren = Open | Close

inductive S where
  S_empty: "S []" |
  S_append: "S xs ⟹ S ys ⟹ S (xs @ ys)" |
  S_paren: "S xs ⟹ S (Open # xs @ [Close])"

inductive T where
  T_S: "T []" |
  T_append: "T xs ⟹ T ys ⟹ T (xs @ ys)" |
  T_paren: "T xs ⟹ T (Open # xs @ [Close])" |
  T_left: "T xs ⟹ T (Open # xs)"
```

The lemma states that an unbalanced parentheses structure would result in a possibly unbalanced structure when removing an `Open` bracket.

I've been trying the techniques that are described in the book "A proof-assistant for Higher-order logic", but so far none of them work. In particular, I tried to use rule inversion and rule induction, `sledgehammer` and other techniques.

One of the problems is that I haven't yet learned about Isar proofs, which thus complicates the proof. I would prefer if you can orient me with plain apply commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a proof below. It is not unlikely that it can be improved: I tried to follow the simplest route towards the proof and relied on `sledgehammer` to fill in the details.

```
theory so_raoidii
imports  Complex_Main

begin

datatype paren = Open | Close

inductive S where
  S_empty: "S []" |
  S_append: "S xs ⟹ S ys ⟹ S (xs @ ys)" |
  S_paren: "S xs ⟹ S (Open # xs @ [Close])"

inductive T where
  T_S: "T []" |
  T_append: "T xs ⟹ T ys ⟹ T (xs @ ys)" |
  T_paren: "T xs ⟹ T (Open # xs @ [Close])" |
  T_left: "T xs ⟹ T (Open # xs)"

lemma count_list_lem: 
  "count_list xsa a = n ⟹ 
  count_list ysa a = m ⟹ 
  count_list (xsa @ ysa) a = n + m"
  apply(induction xsa arbitrary: ysa n m)
  apply auto
  done

lemma T_to_count: "T xs ⟹ count_list xs Close ≤ count_list xs Open"
  apply(induction rule: T.induct)
  by (simp add: count_list_lem)+

lemma T_to_S_count: "T xs ⟹ count_list xs Close = count_list xs Open ⟹ S xs"
  apply(induction rule: T.induct)
  apply(auto)
  apply(simp add: S_empty)
  apply(metis S_append T_to_count add.commute add_le_cancel_right count_list_lem 
        dual_order.antisym)
  apply(simp add: count_list_lem S_paren)
  using T_to_count by fastforce

lemma "T (Open # xs) ⟹ 
      ¬ S (Open # xs) ⟹ 
      count_list xs Close ≤ count_list xs Open"
  apply(cases "T xs")
  apply(simp add: T_to_count)
  using T_to_S_count T_to_count by fastforce

end
```

Comment: i wonder which provers you have in sledgehammer. i think this is one of my problems that vampire is not working well and only have cvc4

Comment: @Rodrigo I am not certain what exactly do you mean by the phrase "vampire is not working well". If you suspect that vampire is not working how it should, then it may be best to ask another question about it (however, this is not something I could help you with). To answer your question, I only use cvc4 and vampire. Also, please note that I meant to say that I relied on `sledgehammer` to fill in the details in my (virtual) 'pen and paper-based' proof outline. Of course, before typesetting the proof in Isabelle, I did produce a proof outline in my mind.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification, in particular the step with smt is not found by my sledgehammer, ill have to work on it.

Comment: @Rodrigo I believe that I created the `smt` step from an explicit Isar lemma that I had in my original answer before editing it. Indeed, I was not able to use `sledgehammer` for this step within `T_to_S_count `.